# Jacoco test.exec generated file is of 0 bytes

Tags: gradle, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

I have gradle multi-module project which has jacoco plugin applied on subprojects and its configuration is as below.

```
jacoco{

        toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"

    }




jacocoTestReport {

        reports {

            xml.enabled true

            csv.enabled true

            html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"

        }

}
```

now when I build with `gradlew clean build` then build is generated and jacoco test report also generated at `html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"` location but "${buildDir}/jacoco" has a file called test.exec which is of 0 bytes. Problem Is when generate build with sonarqube plugin then it is trying to access this file and due to it is of 0 bytes it is throwing error and not generating sonarqube report.

I want to generate sonarqube report while building application. I am using `gradlew clean build sonarqube` command to build. Also, getting below Exception also for the subproject for which test.exec is of 0 bytes.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:203)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_14f7ee5.output.FileOutput.openFile(FileOutput.java:67)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_14f7ee5.output.FileOutput.writeExecutionData(FileOutput.java:53)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_14f7ee5.Agent.shutdown(Agent.java:137)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_14f7ee5.Agent$1.run(Agent.java:54)
```